# Java NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in my Class Article in `line 5`.

In one class I create the object `Article article = new Article()`,
then I call `article.addPrice(quantity, price);` with `quantity` being an Integer with the value '`1`' and `price` being a Float with the value '`1.32`'.

```
1: public class Article {
2:  private List prices;
3:  public void addPrice(Integer quantity, Float qtyPrice){
4:      Price price = new Price(quantity, qtyPrice);
5:      this.prices.add(price);
6:  }
7: }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to initialize the prices list.

```
prices = new ArrayList<Price>();
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use an ArrayList instead of a List? Or is me trying to add an object to a List the reason why I cannot instantiate prices = new List<Price>()?

Comment: List is an interface, ArrayList is a type of list.

Comment: exactly, in Java List is an interface, unlike in C#

Answer (score 5):

Your code never assigns `prices`, therefore the field still contains its initial value, which is `null`.

In plain english, you program would read: Create a new price object and add it to the list I assigned to `prices`. You didn't assign a list, and therefore the computer can't know which list to add to ...

Answer (score 3):

The 'prices' list is not initialized which causes the null reference.

Comment: How can it be fixed? This should be a comment if you aren't going to provide an answer.

Comment: It's not clear whether OP simply wanted to know why the exception was thrown, or also wanted to know how to fix it. If the former, this is a full answer, if the latter, it is a partial one - but it is an answer in either case.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Article
{
 private List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<Price>();

 public void addPrice( Integer quantity, Float qtyPrice )
 {
  Price price = new Price( quantity, qtyPrice );
  prices.add( price );
 }
}
```

Unless you vastly oversimplified the problem, I can't think of any reason the above would not work.

Comment: great answer, is there a reason why you instantiate the list directly rather than in a constructor?

Comment: Instantiating the list in this manner is **exactly** the same as in a constructor. This means the list will be initialized in the synthesized constructor. You will see this in the debugger as <clinit>

Comment: Exactly what Sam said.  You did not mention a constructor in your initial question and I did not want to make any assumptions.  Members initialized in this way will also be instantiated regardless of which constructor is called (if there is more than one) -- with collections, I've always viewed that as important.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized the private list variable. Insert this as the first lines in `addPrice`:

```
if (prices == null) {
    prices = new ArrayList<Price>();
}
```

This will ensure the prices list is initialized prior to being accessed.

Comment: `cannot instantiate the type List<Price>`

Comment: Yes, List is the generic interface. You need to instantiate a list that is appropriate to your code. `ArrayList` is a good start if you are not sure what you need.

Comment: perfect, is there a reason why you suggested `if` instead of a constructor?

Comment: Simply lazy loading. If the article class will always require this array list to be initialized, you should most certainly move it to a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have just declared the list **prices** and not initialized it.

Use following **corrected code** :

```
1:  public class Article {
2:  private List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<Price>();
3:  public void addPrice(Integer quantity, Float qtyPrice){
4:      Price price = new Price(quantity, qtyPrice);
5:      this.prices.add(price);
6:  }
7: }
```

so till the time you do **new ArrayList()**, you have **null** in prices and you are trying to invoke .add(price) on null in line 5, hence the NullPointerException.